# unable to set and get values in localstorage

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

I'm developing a web application in iPhone using Phonegap. In this app, I want to send data from one page to another within the same index.html file. I'm using local storage to send data, but I am unable to send values. whenever the local storage statements are encountered, it skips the remaining statements also in that javascript function. Please tell me the solution. Do I need to add any plugin to use local storage?

```
{
    var name = document.getElementById("usernameTextField").value;   //TextField of page1
    var fullname = document.getElementById("nameLabel").innerHTML;  //label of page1
    localstorage.setItem("userName", name);
    localstorage.setItem("fullname1", fullname); 
    var getusername = localstorage.getItem("userName");
    var getname = localstorage.getItem("fullname1");
    fullnameLabel.innerHTML = getname.value;  //label of page2
    userNameLabel.innerHTML = getusername.value;  //label of page2
}
```

Comment: please share your javascript code which does save/read from localstorage

Comment: I edited my question, please tell me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
{
    var name = document.getElementById("usernameTextField").value;   //TextField
    var fullname = document.getElementById("nameLabel").innerHTML;  //label
    localStorage.setItem("userName", name);
    localStorage.setItem("fullname1", fullname); 
    var getusername = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    var getname = localStorage.getItem("fullname1");
    alert(getname + " " + getusername);  //label

}
```

Please check the full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/tQdAa/)